# Cambiar nombre de una imagen en carpeta

Tags: php, javascript, imagen, archivo

Buen dia, estoy haciendo una página de usuario y en ella hay una opción de cambiar la imagen de perfil. Cuando suben un archivo mi codigo lo comprime y cambia de nombre. Pero si el usuario quiere cambiar de imagen, se guardan dos archivos en la carpeta que los aloja; como puedo eliminar la imagen anterior y conservar la última??

Estaba pensando en cambiar el nombre a la primera imagen como: **"elim"+.$user".jpg"** *(donde $user contiene el id)*  para luego eliminar todas manualmente.

> EDITADO:

```
$idw= id del usuario
```

NOMBRE = **'logo'.$idw.'user.jpg'** o **'logo'.$idw.'user.png'**

Si cambia entre formatos, quedarían 2 imágenes con el mismo nombre.

Comment: No entiendo, si la imagen se guardo como `img1`, entonces primero se elimina y cuando se sube otra imagen, se guarda con el mism nombre. ¿Porque conservar la anterior?

Comment: Tengo un sistema similar, y para ahorrarme una tabla de imágenes, lo que hago es que voy creando las imágenes con la nomenclatura `user1_001.jpg`, `user1_002.jpg`, etc... y en la base de datos solo está el nombre de la imagen actualmente asignada. Para ver el historial de imágenes de `user1`, el sistema busca físicamente todas las `user1_[*].jpg` que encuentre.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias enviar el `src` actual de la imagen alojado en tu tabla y luego desde `PHP` antes de borrar la imagen y actualizar la información, primero deberías intentar subir la nueva, (ya que así te aseguras de tener aún la imagen anterior por si algo falla).

En caso de que no hayan problemas al subir la nueva imagen, entonces simplemente borras la anterior, que como ya tienes la informacion de la anterior simplemente es usar esta informacion con la funcion `unlink`, luego simplemente actualizas el `src` de la imagen en la tabla.

Me explico:

```
//Requerimos la conexion a la base de datos creada con PDO en este caso
require "conexion.php";

//Obtenemos el src enviado desde el cliente y la nueva imagen
$src = $_POST["src"];
$newSrc = $_FILES["newImg"];
$orgName = substr($src, 0, strpos("."));
$orgExtension = substr($src, strpos(".") + 1);
$newImgExtension = $newSrc["type"];

//Subimos la nueva imagen:
move_uploaded_file($orgName . $newImgExtension, "/images");

/*Quiere decir que como las extensiones son diferentes la imagen no sera sobreescrita
  Por lo tanto debemos eliminar la imagen antigua manualmente y cambiar la extension de
  la imagen en la tabla.
*/
if($orgExtension != $newImgExtension){
   unlink($src);

   //Consulta para actualizar la ruta de la imagen con la nueva extension
   $query = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE tabla SET src = :src WHERE src = :src2");
   $query->execute(
      array(
         ":src" => $src,
         ":src2" => $orgName . $newImgExtension
      )
   );
}
```

Este es el caso en que quieres que la imagen conserve el mismo nombre pero puede diferir en extension, de esta manera eliminariamos la imagen antigua y conservariamos siempre la nueva pero bajo el mismo nombre, ademas de actualizar esta informacion en la tabla.

En caso contrario puedes modificar este ejemplo a tu conveniencia. notese que no es necesario entrar al condicional si las extensiones son iguales, ya que lo que hara `PHP` es simplemente sobreescribir los datos del archivo si ya existe.